# JSON architecture

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having some difficulty managing concrete Swift objects and their associated JSON representations.

Here are two objects in my app (removed many properties for brevity):

#### Token.swift

```
struct Token {
  let user: User
}
```

#### User.swift

```
final class User {
  var tokens: [Token] = []
}
```

These two types reference each other. I need to save this in JSON format to **Firebase**, which is a JSON based backend service.

Unfortunately, JSON cannot accept complex objects such as `Token` and `User`. Thus, I'll need to reference them in another way, such as through a unique identifier (**UUID**):

#### Token.swift with UUID

```
struct Token {
  let user: User
  let uniqueIdentifier: UUID // a universally unique identifier 
}
```

#### User.swift with UUID

```
final class User {
  var tokens: [Token] = [] 
  let uniqueIdentifier: UUID // a universally unique identifier
}
```

I made this cleaner by giving both model objects a `json` property, which is a computed property that returns a dictionary representation of the object:

#### Token.swift with JSON computed property

```
extension Token {
  var json: [String: Any] {
    return [
      "user": user.uniqueIdentifier,
      "uniqueIdentifier": uniqueIdentifier
    ]
  }
}
```

#### User.swift with JSON computed property

```
extension User {
  var json: [String: Any] {
    return [
      "tokens": tokens.map { $0.uniqueIdentifier.uuidString },
      "uniqueIdentifier: uniqueIdentifier
    ]
  }
}
```

This allows me to save these objects into **Firebase** elegantly:

```
tokensRef.setValue(token.json)
usersRef.setValue(user.json)
```

This gives me the current JSON structure:

```
root
 |
  -- tokens
 |      |
 |       -- ASDF 
 |            |
 |             -- uniqueIdentifier: "ASDF"
 |            |
 |             -- user: "FDSA"
 |
  -- users
 |      |
 |       -- FDSA
 |            |
 |             -- uniqueIdentifier: "FDSA"
 |            |
 |             -- tokens
 |                  | 
 |                   -- ASDF
```

There's some duplication of information in this nested structure, but as the **Firebase** [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data) states:

> Because the Firebase Realtime Database allows nesting data up to 32 levels deep, you might be tempted to think that this should be the default structure. However, when you fetch data at a location in your database, you also retrieve all of its child nodes. In addition, when you grant someone read or write access at a node in your database, you also grant them access to all data under that node. Therefore, in practice, it's best to keep your data structure as flat as possible.

The structure looks fine (to me). But I ran into a problem.

### The Problem

Converting the object back to JSON has been a problem. Consider this call to **Firebase**:

```
func fetchTokens(completion: @escaping ([Token]) -> ()) {
  tokensRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: [String: Any]] else { fatalError() }

    var tokens: [Token] = []
    for (key, value) in dict {
      guard let uniqueIdentifier = value["uniqueIdentifier"] as? String,
            let user = value["user"] as? String else { fatalError() }

      // problem here
      let token = Token(uniqueIdentifier: uniqueIdentifier, user: <#user#>) 
      tokens.append(token)
    }
    completion(tokens)
  })
}
```

Since the JSON structure is done the way it is, this makes it hard to reconstruct the model classes. The token dictionary contains the unique identifier of the `User`, but not the other information. I would have to make another asynchronous call to fetch it, which makes the code incredibly unruly to deal with.

Does anyone have any advice on how to structure the data to help deal with this problem?

Comment: What exactly is `User`? Is it  `FDSA`??..

Comment: Yeah, `FDSA` is my pseudo `uuid`

Comment: I cant really unserstand your issue here.Your code seems about right. Are you not getting user value? If you are looking for a specific user or a node that contains a particular child with a particular value w/o going through all the data and looping it over , you can use queryOrderedByChild("...").